# How to load data in two section of table view iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 sections within a table view and I have loaded one section from one array and one from another. How can I set cell values for both sections?

I'm using the following code:

Title For Header Section.

```
   - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:                             (NSInteger)section
   {
        if(section == 0)       
            return @" Scheduled Patients ";
        else
            return @" Walk In Patients ";
   }
```

Rows in Section:

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

    if(section==0)
        return [resultArray count];
    else {
      EMRAppDelegate *appDelegate = (EMRAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      return [appDelegate.walkPatients count];
    }
  }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


     {
       UIButton * uploadButton = nil;
       static NSString * Identifier = @"Identifier";
       UITableViewCell * cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
      if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:Identifier] autorelease];
       uploadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
       [uploadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 24, 24)];
       [uploadButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"upload.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [uploadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onUploadButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       [uploadButton setTag:999];
       cell.accessoryView = uploadButton;
      }
     else {
     uploadButton = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
     }



     EMRAppDelegate *appDelegate = (EMRAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


   ObjectData *theCellData =[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   WalkPatient * patient = [ appDelegate.walkPatients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   if (indexPath.section == 0)
   {
    // do coding for cell loading for Scheduled Patients 


     cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
     cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", theCellData.firstName, theCellData.lasttName];

      if (patient.syncDate != nil) {
        UIImageView * checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]];
        [checkmark setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 12, 12)];
        [checkmark setTag:998];
        [uploadButton addSubview:checkmark];
        [checkmark release];
        [uploadButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(onUploadButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"];
        cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Synched: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:patient.syncDate]];
        [dateFormatter release];
         } 
        else {
        UIView * checkmark = (UIView *)[uploadButton viewWithTag:998];
        if (checkmark != nil) {
            [checkmark removeFromSuperview];
         }
       }

       cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

      return cell;

       }

    else
     {
    // do load cells for    Walk In Patients. 





       cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
       cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", patient.firstName, patient.lastName];

       if (patient.syncDate != nil) {
       UIImageView * checkmark = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]];
       [checkmark setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 12, 12)];
       [checkmark setTag:998];
       [uploadButton addSubview:checkmark];
       [checkmark release];
       [uploadButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(onUploadButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm"];
         cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
         cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Synched: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:patient.syncDate]];
         [dateFormatter release];
      } 
      else {
        UIView * checkmark = (UIView *)[uploadButton viewWithTag:998];
        if (checkmark != nil) {
        [checkmark removeFromSuperview];
        }
      }

      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

       return cell;


      }
   }
```

Comment: question how to load values in cell table view for two sections

Comment: +1 as you made some efforts before asking question.

Comment: What happened? Code did not work?

Comment: code work but when i click on segment button it crashes and says unrecognised selector sent

Comment: What you asked in question I replied based on that. Unrecognised selector error generally occurs when you miss some IBOutlet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method also you put one condition to check the section and load data according to them.

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    // do coding for cell loading for Scheduled Patients 
      UIButton *btnsection0=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [btnsection0 addTarget:self action:@selector(showProject:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

else
{
     // do load cells for    Walk In Patients. 
      UIButton *btnsection1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
      [btnsection0 addTarget:self action:@selector(showProject:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 }
```

Comment: but it gives exception and not runs

Comment: reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' when it comes second array line

Comment: Its because your array is empty and you are trying to fetch data from it. Its something like trying to withdraw 1000 rupees from an ATM which is out  of money.

Comment: What does this two lines do?

     ObjectData *theCellData =[resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

      WalkPatient * patient = [ appDelegate.walkPatients objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Have you implemented Core data in your project?

Comment: not too much only one table other data i am getting from server

Comment: Please have a look at this [code sample](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=iphone%20core%20data%20recipies&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fsamplecode%2FiPhoneCoreDataRecipes%2FListings%2FReadMe_txt.html&ei=PIB-T5jCHsLPrQf8sKnnBQ&usg=AFQjCNFv-04vLHrcyLUa_aQdyZrdtFFSoQ): Try to understand. You will get your answer.

Comment: is it for section as discussed

Comment: Yes. Please see.. Because from your code I do can not figure out your issue.. You are calling an object of array which does not exists.

Comment: Found that helpful?? If any queries come to chat room.. I will be there.

Comment: ok thanks for helping if found any problem i will come to chat room

Comment: i have to ask one thing i have button like upload can i throw different action for these two sections on same button

Comment: how to have i have just changed the button action selector in ohter section but it is not working

Comment: You create UIButton every time in cellforRowAtIndexPath. and select action method for it.

Comment: how to do this i am creating button like above code can u edit my code

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it.  The cellForRowAtIndexPath method comes with an indexPath parameter that can give you:

```
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
```

Please, always, always make cellForRowAtIndexPath logic mirror the numberOfRowsInSection logic, so when you get asked for a row count:

```
return (section==0)? [array0 count] : [array1 count];
```

... and when you get asked for a cell, and you need the data for that cell

```
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
NSInteger section = indexPath.section;

NSArray *arrayForThisSection = (section==0)? array0 : array1;
id elementForThisRow = [arrayForThisSection objectAtIndex:row];

// config the cell with elementForThisRow
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) for [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource):
`UITableView declares a category on NSIndexPath that enables you to get the represented row index (row property) and section index (section property),`

So you can go `indexPath.section` and it'll tell you which section the tableview wants to populate.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btnsection0=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{ 
  btnsection0.tag =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
}else{ 
  btnsection0.tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
}
[btnsection0 addTarget:self action:@selector(showProject:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

button event

```
-(IBAction)showProject:(id)sender{
      NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
      int section = [[s substringToIndex:1] intValue];
      int row = [[s substringFromIndex:0] intValue];

}
```